Does it make sense to consider function, that has finite zero value at limit point as "infinitely small"?
Studying the calculus, I am currently reading the chapter "Comparison of infinitely small functions". It is started to overview ratios such as
$$\lim_{x->x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 \space,  \space \lim_{x->x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$$
, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are infinitely small functions.
I assume, that by "infinitely small at limit point $x_0$ function" meant $\lim_{x->x_0}f(x)=0$.
Reading, I started to think about examples, and I could provide only $f(x)=\dfrac{a}{x}$ at infinity.
But then, I see examples of infinitely smalls like $f(x)=x$ at $x->0$.

According to the limit definition, since $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$ considered as deleted, i.e. $0<|x-x_0|<\delta(\epsilon)$, it seems, like, formally, there is no requirement for function value at limit point itself.
I understand why - for cases like $1/x$, but exactly because of this, as I understand, the idea of infinitely small was invented - to describe the smallest, yet non-zero value, and so called "infinitely small (function)" is what mathematics such as Euler, Cauchy, and other invented.
If it is true, is not consider functions such $x^3$ as infinitely small intuitively wrong, or I missing some ideas?

Maybe historically, the idea of limit of function as argument tends to limit point - was the closest function value to function value at limit point?
But the method of finding the closest value to some point was not found, and instead, we have vice-versa: we found a point, that is called an accumulating point, which any $\epsilon$-neighourhood contains at least one value of function at some another accumulating point, called limit point.
So it still makes sense to find what is the closest value of $0$ for $x^3$, but calculus does not provide such tool, instead providing the tool to compare that infinitely small value to another, for example $x^2$, because, how it may be non-logical, we see that "infinitely closest" to $0$ of $x^3$ is different from "infinitely closest" to $0$ of $x^2$?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Short answer: yes, it makes sense
The key is that the only thing, that seems to have no sense, at least in terms of Calculus (Analysis, I do not know what is the difference) is to consider an infinitively small value to some finite point, not relatively to some law, of how the variable is tends to reach some finite point.
If we consider some function, for example $x^3$, we know that it somehow decreases, if we will consider it values from some positive to the zero.
Calculus does not tell what is the last value that $x^3$ will take for some $x_0$ right before $0$ at $x=0$, it tells that it is just is what is called an "infinitively small" (noun).
However, what Calculus tells, that infinitively small of $x^3$ "near" $x=0$ is different from infinitively small of $x^2$ "near" same $x=0$, and how much it is different.
So, this is what that statement in books means

Do not consider infinitively small as static number. One should consider infinitively small as a dynamic value, sort-of a function.

In Calculus, infinitively small is not a finite value, that one can measure, but a "thing", that has it own behaviour, that may be different from another.
This is, also, why, as I understand, it has no sense, in terms of Calculus to consider infinitively closest point to some point, without some function, that describes the law, how variable reaches that point.

A bit more intuitive explanation
Imagine some people, that want to know the closest value to some another number, for example, the closest to 5 (whatever from which side), not even necessary to zero.
So, people say: "it is 5.001", "no, it is 5.000001", "no, 5.000000001 is smaller".
They will not, according to Calculus:

Name the closest.
Compare their "guesses".

But if now, people will again enumerate the closest to $5$, but not randomly, but according to some law, of how the "candidate" to being the closest is changed, i.e. according to some function, being "synchronized" with step between arguments, they will see, that two functions, that both tends to $5$ at some $x_0$, reaches it in different way: one faster and one slower.
So, one of the people, may always name closer value to $5$, then another, even, though, another, after enumerating some value may reach such value, but the first one, again will already "go further" for that moment and so on.
In that case, according to Calculus:

Noone still will not name the closest
But now, two or more "infinitely small" can be compared.


Relevant: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/
